# Google Drive Files.list: 500 error

Tags: google-drive-api

For our application we are using Google Drive SDK with 2-legged authorization.
We are using Drive SDK for a long time, but today we faced with new issue for Files.list API (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list).  For some users, from different domains we got following error:

> { "error": { "code": 500, "message": null } }

Is everything OK with Drive SDK? What does this error mean?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13543366/453348) that helped me to configure and connect to Google Drive with Android

**EDIT:**

I had the same 500 error server, to avoid this error Google recommend the [`Exponential backoff`](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads?hl=en#exp-backoff) that according to them:

> Exponential backoff is a standard error handling strategy for network
>   applications in which the client periodically retries a failed request
>   over an increasing amount of time. If a high volume of requests or
>   heavy network traffic causes the server to return errors, exponential
>   backoff may be a good strategy for handling those errors. Conversely,
>   it is not a relevant strategy for dealing with errors unrelated to
>   rate-limiting, network volume or response times, such as invalid
>   authorization credentials or file not found errors.
>
> Used properly, exponential backoff increases the efficiency of
>   bandwidth usage, reduces the number of requests required to get a
>   successful response, and maximizes the throughput of requests in
>   concurrent environments.

**Example:**

Android code:

```
FileList files = null;

for (int n = 0; n < 5; ++n) {

   try {
      setStatus("trying n = " + n);
      files = service.files()
        .list()
        .setMaxResults(1)
        .setQ("mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and title = 'folder_title'")
        .execute();
   }
   catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e)
   {
      if (e.getDetails().getCode() == 500) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep((1 << n) * 1000 + randomGenerator.nextInt(1001));
            setStatus("sleep() n = " + n);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            setStatus("InterruptedException n = " + n + " " + e1.getMessage());
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
   }

}
```

I have tested this code and in the last try it connects successfully

Google recommend to use the Exponential backoff with 4xx and 5xx server [error](https://developers.google.com/drive/handle-errors)

The [4xx server](https://developers.google.com/drive/handle-errors#implementing_exponential_backoff) errors are mostly for authentication problem