# Google Drive on android error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null

Tags: android, google-drive-api, illegalargumentexception

I got stuck with an "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null" Exception on Google Drive Android app.

I have been googling several day without getting any clue. 
This is my code (an easy example) to get a file list on Google Drive:
(It was taken from here: [Google Drive SDK Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462952/google-drive-sdk-exception))

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.BearerToken;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import     com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.accounts.GoogleAccountManager;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveRequest;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;
import com.maiko.xscanpet.R;
import com.maiko.xscanpet.cloud.GDriveHelper;

public class Fool_5 extends Activity {
private static final int CHOOSE_ACCOUNT=0;
private static String accountName;
private static int REQUEST_TOKEN=0;
private Button btn_drive;
private Context ctx = this;
private Activity a = this;

GoogleAccountCredential mCredential= null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // set up the GUI layout
    setContentView(R.layout.fool_5);
    // set the variables to access the GUI controls
    btn_drive = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_drive);
        btn_drive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            chooseAccount();
        }
        });
}

public void chooseAccount() {
    Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[]{"com.google"}, false, null, null, null, null);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_ACCOUNT);
}

// Fetch the access token asynchronously.
void getAndUseAuthTokenInAsyncTask(Account account) {
    AsyncTask<Account, String, String> task = new AsyncTask<Account, String, String>() {
        ProgressDialog progressDlg;
        AsyncTask<Account, String, String> me = this;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDlg = new ProgressDialog(ctx, ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDlg.setMax(100);
            progressDlg.setTitle("Validating...");
            progressDlg.setMessage("Verifying the login data you entered...\n\nThis action will time out after 10 seconds.");
            progressDlg.setCancelable(false);
            progressDlg.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDlg.setOnCancelListener(new android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface d) {
                    progressDlg.dismiss();
                    me.cancel(true);
                }
            });
            progressDlg.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Account... params) {
            return getAccessToken(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            if (s == null) {
                // Wait for the extra intent
            } else {
                accountName = s;
                getDriveFiles();
            }
            progressDlg.dismiss();
        }
    };
    task.execute(account);
}

/**
 * Fetches the token from a particular Google account chosen by the user.  DO NOT RUN THIS DIRECTLY.  It must be run asynchronously inside an AsyncTask.
 * @param activity
 * @param account
 * @return
 */
private String getAccessToken(Account account) {
    try {
        return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(ctx, account.name, "oauth2:" + DriveScopes.DRIVE);  // IMPORTANT: DriveScopes must be changed depending on what level of access you want
    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
        // Start the Approval Screen intent, if not run from an Activity, add the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.
        a.startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_TOKEN);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

private Drive getDriveService() {
    mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE);
    mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
    return GDriveHelper.getDriveService(mCredential,getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));

}

/**
 * Obtains a list of all files on the signed-in user's Google Drive account.
 */
private void getDriveFiles() {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Drive service = getDriveService();
            Log.d("SiteTrack", "FUNCTION getDriveFiles()");
            Files.List request;
            try {
                request = service.files().list(); // .setQ("mimeType=\"text/plain\"");
            } catch (IOException e) {


                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
            do {
                FileList files;
                try {
                    System.out.println("got here");
                    Log.d("SiteTrack", request.toString());
                    //mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                    files = request.execute();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("SiteTrack", "Exception");
                    return;
                }
                ArrayList<File> fileList = (ArrayList<File>) files.getItems();
                Log.d("SiteTrack", "Files found: " + files.getItems().size());
                for (File f : fileList) {
                    String fileId = f.getId();
                    String title = f.getTitle();
                    Log.d("SiteTrack", "File " + fileId + ": " + title);
                }
                request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
            } while (request.getPageToken() != null && request.getPageToken().length() >= 0);
        }
    });
    t.start();

}

protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CHOOSE_ACCOUNT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
        GoogleAccountManager gam = new GoogleAccountManager(this);
        getAndUseAuthTokenInAsyncTask(gam.getAccountByName(accountName));
        Log.d("SiteTrack", "CHOOSE_ACCOUNT");
    } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_TOKEN && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
        Log.d("SiteTrack", "REQUEST_TOKEN");
    }
}   
}
```

This generates the this trace on files = request.execute(); or any request.execute():

```
04-20 01:40:26.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27203): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-39033
04-20 01:40:26.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27203): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null
04-20 01:40:26.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27203):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1429)
04-20 01:40:26.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27203):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
04-20 01:40:26.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27203):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.x$a$a.a(Unknown Source)
04-20 01:40:26.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27203):    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
04-20 01:40:26.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27203):    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
04-20 01:40:26.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27203):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:192)
04-20 01:40:26.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27203):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:217)
04-20 01:40:26.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27203):    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:888)
04-20 01:40:26.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27203):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:407)
04-20 01:40:26.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27203):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:340)
04-20 01:40:26.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27203):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:458)
04-20 01:40:26.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27203):    at com.maiko.fool.Fool_5$3.run(Fool_5.java:184)
04-20 01:40:26.105: E/AndroidRuntime(27203):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I feel lost about this, without no clue about what could be wrong.I have followed this tutorial about configuring Google API Services: https://plus.google.com/u/0/114042449736049687152/posts/CD3L8zcJg5Z

Thank you for your help.

Comment: at com.maiko.fool.Fool_5$3.run(Fool_5.java:184) - what is line 184?

Comment: 184 is: files = request.execute(); (as said before the trace)

Comment: @MaikoMobile have u got the solution of this issue? I am also facing the same issue at my side , I have set selected Account name as well.

Answer (score 7):

For other people facing the same problem ,

Try credential.setAccount() instead of credential.setAccountName();

as there is an additional "type" parameter in an account object which is required sometimes . For storage you could do something as in the case below : (pseudo code)

```
GoogleSignInAccount account = initAccount();
Account acct = account.getAccount();
storeStringInPrefs("NAME" , acct.name);
storeStringInPrefs("TYPE" , acct.type);
```

Then for retrieval

```
GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOauth(...);
String name = getPrefs("NAME");
String type = getPrefs("TYPE");
credential.setSelectedAccount(new Account(name , type));
```

Now it should work :D , This is just pseudo code for your basic understanding and will not work if copied into your project.

Comment: Best answer, fixed issue in my case!

Comment: Thanks I improvised and did this: `credentials.setSelectedAccount(acct.getAccount());`

Answer (score 5):

verify the var "accountName" you are passing to the "mCredential" object. Usually thats the reason of those errors.
Greetings.

Comment: Since when did the GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() method start throwing a GoogleAuthException with message "BadUsername" for an email that is not registered on a device, instead of the previous exception IllegalArgumentException with message "Non existing account 'email_address'" ?  
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html#getToken(android.content.Context , java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

Just add `.requestEmail()` to signing options :

```
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder options =
                            new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                                    .requestEmail()
                                    .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA));
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this when `@gmail.com` was missing from the user name. Thought it was optional because it is in most Google forms...

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure the **READ_CONTACTS** permission is enabled. I got the same error while using Youtube Data API v3 because of the permission.