# Invalid Credential for Google Drive API in Android

Tags: android, oauth, google-drive-api

Possible duplicate

Hello Friends,

I have refer this [Google Drive SDK Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462952/google-drive-sdk-exception), actually I got this error

```
07-18 13:07:49.252: W/System.err(16389): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized

07-18 13:07:49.252: W/System.err(16389): {
07-18 13:07:49.252: W/System.err(16389):   "code" : 401,
07-18 13:07:49.260: W/System.err(16389):   "errors" : [ {
07-18 13:07:49.260: W/System.err(16389):     "domain" : "global",
07-18 13:07:49.260: W/System.err(16389):     "location" : "Authorization",
07-18 13:07:49.260: W/System.err(16389):     "locationType" : "header",
07-18 13:07:49.260: W/System.err(16389):     "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
07-18 13:07:49.260: W/System.err(16389):     "reason" : "authError"
07-18 13:07:49.267: W/System.err(16389):   } ],
07-18 13:07:49.267: W/System.err(16389):   "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
07-18 13:07:49.267: W/System.err(16389): }
```

I have been spending 2 days to solve this error but no luck, has anybody implemented Google Drive API to access file and/or upload file?

Please need your help

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `GoogleAccountCredential` to authorize and authenticate your requests.

```
GoogleAccountCredential credential =
    GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE);

Drive service = new Drive
    .Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential)
    .build();

service.files().list().execute();
```

A quickstart tutorial is available on https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android

Comment: I have also tried using this way but when executing execute() it fails with invalid credentials I don't know why. Thanks for the reply

Comment: It's strange. Play services take care of token refreshment and etc.

Comment: Can you post complete flow I think I have wrong way implemented thats why I have getting this error my code was same as I have posted another stack question

Comment: The quickstart app on https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android contains the complete flow, fyi.