# Accessing Google Drive through Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to access the google drive through android app. I have turned on the `Drive API` and `Drive SDK` in Google Developer Console and generated a OAuth Client id.

Inserted the Client key in `AndroidManifest.xml` as

```
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID"
  android:value=id="***CLIENT_KEY***" />
```

And a permission as

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

This is the code which I am trying to run (Originally from [here](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/quickstart/MainActivity.java))

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.DriveContentsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.MetadataChangeSet;

/**
 * Android Drive Quickstart activity. This activity takes a photo and saves it
 * in Google Drive. The user is prompted with a pre-made dialog which allows
 * them to choose the file location.
 */

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
    OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String TAG = "android-drive-quickstart";
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR = 2;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 3;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Bitmap mBitmapToSave;

/**
 * Create a new file and save it to Drive.
 */
private void saveFileToDrive() {
    // Start by creating a new contents, and setting a callback.
    Log.i(TAG, "Creating new contents.");
    final Bitmap image = mBitmapToSave;
    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
            // If the operation was not successful, we cannot do anything
            // and must
            // fail.
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Failed to create new contents.");
                return;
            }
            // Otherwise, we can write our data to the new contents.
            Log.i(TAG, "New contents created.");
            // Get an output stream for the contents.
            OutputStream outputStream = result.getDriveContents().getOutputStream();
            // Write the bitmap data from it.
            ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bitmapStream);
            try {
                outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Unable to write file contents.");
            }
            // Create the initial metadata - MIME type and title.
            // Note that the user will be able to change the title later.
            MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setMimeType("image/jpeg").setTitle("Android Photo.png").build();
            // Create an intent for the file chooser, and start it.
            IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                    .newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                    .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                    .setInitialDriveContents(result.getDriveContents())
                    .build(mGoogleApiClient);
            try {
                startIntentSenderForResult(
                        intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Failed to launch file chooser.");
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        // Create the API client and bind it to an instance variable.
        // We use this instance as the callback for connection and connection
        // failures.
        // Since no account name is passed, the user is prompted to choose.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
    // Connect the client. Once connected, the camera is launched.
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE:
            // Called after a photo has been taken.
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Store the image data as a bitmap for writing later.
                mBitmapToSave = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR:
            // Called after a file is saved to Drive.
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Image successfully saved.");
                mBitmapToSave = null;
                // Just start the camera again for another photo.
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE),
                        REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        // show the localized error dialog.
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
        return;
    }
    // The failure has a resolution. Resolve it.
    // Called typically when the app is not yet authorized, and an
    // authorization
    // dialog is displayed to the user.
    try {
        result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Log.i(TAG, "API client connected.");
    if (mBitmapToSave == null) {
        // This activity has no UI of its own. Just start the camera.
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE),
                REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
        return;
    }
    saveFileToDrive();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
}
}
```

This is the error I am getting

```
02-19 18:58:18.204  27221-27221/com.gajendraprofile.drive I/android-drive-quickstart﹕ GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}
02-19 18:58:47.584  27431-27431/com.gajendraprofile.drive I/android-drive-quickstart﹕ GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{21b27910: android.os.BinderProxy@21b00a7c}}
02-19 18:58:51.564  27431-27431/com.gajendraprofile.drive I/android-drive-quickstart﹕ GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}`
```

Am I making any errors above? Are there any better simple example to access Google Drive from Android?

Comment: Where is the "Inserted the Client key in AndroidManifest.xml as..." coming from? I never heard or used anything similar.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I saw adding manifest key from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412134/how-do-i-use-the-google-drive-api-key-to-access-drive-content-from-android-appli) in the last comment. I have searched many websites and forum. I could not able to find how the client id key should be assigned or linked to the app. Do I need to assign the api key in manifest same like Google Maps Api Key. or I just need to  generate the key with my package name in google console and it will be automatically fetched when the request is sent from the app?.

Comment: BTW, for running any of the demos, I needed only DriveAPI (not DriveSDK). But this is probably irrelevant

Comment: I looked at the link you mention in the comment above. The GDAA came in Jan 2014, and changed a few times during last year. No question / answer older than circa March 2014 has much relevance.

Answer (score 0):

The [Quick Start](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart) you play with as as simple as it gets, to answer you question.

But it may be outdated (I don't know, last time I ran it was 8 months ago). GooPlayServices are on the 6.5.+ version and last update of that code was half a year ago. I have some [code on GitHub](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo) that I can't claim is simpler, but (probably) more in line with current lib version. It is a bit broader and deals with both [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started) and [REST](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) APIs, as well as with the *Google account pick process*. If you use Android Studio, you should be able to make use of it. 
Just a few points:

- You have go through the [Developers Console stuff](https://console.developers.google.com). Basically you must have your 'package name' / SHA1 registered. I usually register both debug and release SHA1s and double check if my APKs are actually correct - see [SO 28532206](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532206/google-oauth-2-0-and-debug-key-for-google-drive-api)
- Look at [SO 28439129 here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439129/how-to-acknowledge-when-user-doesnt-want-to-connect-to-google-play-services) to get some sense what is involved in connecting to GooDrive
- If you use the code I mentioned, make sure you environment is in line with dependencies in 'build.gradle' there (my SDK Manager shows GooPlaySvcs 21, which is 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87')

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

This error "GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null} " occurs if you have not created credentials for your application.

- Go to console- https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials
- Click on Create Credentials
- Select QAuth client ID
- Select Application type as Android if you are running from AndroidStudio
- Add the projectname, SHA key & package name
- Run the project and the application should work.

I faced issue running android-quickstart-master and the issue got resolved after following the above steps